# What is this crosshair-like icon in xcode 6 beta 2?

Tags: xcode6

Updated to xcode 6 beta 2 today and this icon showed up. I have never seen this before. I'm fairly new to xcode, so maybe this is not xcode 6 specific.

Crosshair-like icon on the right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLu23.png

Comment: Looks to me like the color picker.

Comment: Ah thanks. After opening and closing the color picker it's finally gone.

Comment: Seems to be a common issue. For me, it was stuck right over the code area for almost two days....had no idea what it was, thank you.